# jquery check ip before doing rest of stuff

Tags: php, jquery

Hey all, I have a jquery script that's a pretty fun game, you can view it here [link text](http://jsfiddle.net/DHPQT/2/).

now after the play button is clicked, I send the users ip via ajax to see if it matches an ip stored with my site. if it does then the rest of the action is performed. I'm having trouble getting the 1st ajax to work. here's the script.

```
var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;

function IsNumeric(n) {
return !isNaN(n);
}

$("#getit").click(function() {
var hitCount = 0,
missCount = 0;
$('#hitcount').text(0);
$('#misscount').text(0);

/* ajax to check ip goes here if successful they below is performed*/  

$('#message').hide(100);        
var li = [],
    intervals = 0,
    n = parseInt($('#MyNumber').val());

var intervalId = -1;
if (IsNumeric(n)) {
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        li[intervals++ % li.length].text(Math.random() > .1 ? Math.floor(Math.random()     * (10 + n) + (n / 2)) : n).attr('class', '');
    }, <?php echo $time ?>);
}

$('#randomnumber').empty();

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    li.push($('<li />').appendTo('#randomnumber'));
}

$('#randomnumber').delegate("li", "click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if (!$this.hasClass('clicked')) {
            if (parseInt($this.text(), 10) === n) {
                $this.addClass('correct');
                $('#hitcount').text(++hitCount);
            } else {
                $this.addClass('wrong');
                $('#misscount').text(++missCount);
            }

            //New code If the missCount > 3 stop the game and save the value
            if(missCount>=2){
               clearInterval(intervalId);
               $('#randomnumber').undelegate("li", "click");
                // Use a ajax request to save the values

$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'FBhighscore_hwnd.php',
dataType : 'json',
data: {
tgameid: $('#tgameid').val(),MyNumber: $('#MyNumber').val(),totalHits: hitCount
},
success : function(data){
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
.text(data.msg).show(500);
if (data.error === true)
$('#loginForm').show(500);
else
$('#send').hide(500);       
},
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
$('#waiting').hide(500);
$('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
.text('There was an error.').show(500);
$('#loginForm').show(500); 
}
});

            }
        }

        $this.addClass('clicked');
    });

return false;
});
```

Comment: What does it do? What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: check to see if the ip address is attached to a current members ip address. I'm looking for ways to prevent score manipulation.

Comment: Great, but in what way is the code that you posted not behaving that you think it should be behaving?

Comment: the ajax request after the getit button is click isn't working for me. It sends the ip address to a php file. The php file checks if the ip address is in our database, if it's successful the rest of the script is continued, if it's not successful the rest of the script is not executed.

Comment: So is the code that you're showing us what's in the success callback function for that AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

In the php file in the ajax post you could validate the ip against the users ip
Such as...
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $user_ip)) { //do stuff }